# Ionic switch between 2 footers

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, footer

I have this in the footer :

```
<div class="bar bar-footer bar-assertive" ng-show="withdarawStatus">
    <button class="button button-assertive" id="applyButton" ng-click="withdraw()">
        Successfully Applied! Withdraw? 
    </button>
</div>    

<div class="bar bar-footer bar-positive" ng-show="!withdarawStatus" >
    <p id="applyButton" >Application Withdrawn</p>
</div>
```

I want to write a function that when I click withdraw() the footer changes to "Application Withdraw" footer.

I tried this but it didn't work, unless i reload the entire page.

```
$scope.withdraw = function() {
    $scope.withdrawStatus = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your HTML `ng-show="!withdarawStatus"` should be `ng-show="!withdrawStatus"`. That should fix the issue.

Edit: Here's a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/tanmayrajani/pen/QKkYVd)

Comment: Hi there, thank you for noticing that. I made the changes but the issue remains. Unless i reload the entire page, the footer doesn't change.

Comment: @noor check the updated answer. I added your example in codepen.

Comment: while it works in the codepen it doesn;t work on application. I copied the code as it is. I can't really tell what's wrong. When I click on it, nothing happens.

Comment: @noor best guess, controller / ng-app is not bind properly. What happens if you put a console log or alert inside the function `withdraw`? It should show up if controller and app are binding properly.

Comment: when i put the "console.log ('button is clicked'), that message shows in the console. But the actual content change doesn;t take place

Comment: Can you share more code on codepen or fiddle, I can't really help you with just this information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126056/discussion-between-tanmay-and-noor).